# NoMethodError in SessionsController#create undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error that I have not been able to figure out. Here is a link to my entire project on Github: https://github.com/adamskriger/props_data_modeling. I will paste the relevant error and the relevant parts of my code below. If anyone can figure out why I am getting this error, I would very much appreciate it. I have tried the solutions offered by others with similar problems and none seem to work.

This is the error I am getting: [image]

This is what my console shows:
[image]
This is my sessions controller:

```

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new

  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      flash[:success] = "You have successfully logged in"
      redirect_to user_path(user)
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "There was something wrong with your login information"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:success] = "You have logged out"
    redirect_to root_path
  end


end
```

```

This is my sessions/new.html.erb

```

```
<h1 align="center">Log in</h1>

<%= form_for(:session, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}, url: login_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
      <%= f.label :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter email", autofocus: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
      <%= f.label :password %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <%= f.submit "Log in", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
  [ <%= link_to "Cancel request and return to articles listing", props_path %> ]
</div>
```

```
This is my users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
    end
end
```

[image]

Comment: please add your `params` result from create action

Comment: may be your `params[:session]` result is nil

Comment: params[:session] is nil. But if I have my create method as ```render 'new'``` then the params for session do show up when I submit the form. So the bottleneck is somewhere between there.

Answer (score 0):

hi please try replacing your `form_for` syntax like below

```
<%= form_for :session, url: login_path, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>
```

It may help :-)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: I am now getting a different error. I don't know what I did but for some reason my code started working.

Comment: ohh that's great... :-)